# SharePoint OOTB Alert still sends an email even after deleting all instances of it

Tags: alert

A while back we deleted an Alert on a list (the only Alert that was set on the list), yet an email is still being sent out, and when we try to check the settings of the Alerts on the list (and also follow the Alert email's "modify my alert settings" link), no Alerts show as existing. What is going on with this "ghost/rogue" Alert email? The URL of the Alert Settings is:

"domain/_layouts/MySubs.aspx"

So this tells me that just possibly it will only display Alerts I am subscribed to, which I am not for this list. Might it be that only the user receiving the emails can see the Alerts on this settings page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,
You are absolutely correct. You have users still subscribed to the alerts. This is a confusing part of using Sharepoint alerts.

You can verify this by taking the following steps:
Navigate to your site>>Site Actions>>Site Settings>>Under Site Administration, Click "User Alerts" >> On the very top of the page you will see a drop down, you can choose the name of a person who claims they are receiving duplicate or unwanted alerts. >> Click Update >> All Subscribed Alerts will be displayed. >> Delete the unwanted alerts and the problem is solved!

-Rounn QED'd